# manipulate Date from yfinance

Tags: python, datetime, yfinance

When I pull stock data from yfinance, can I create other columns of data that manipulate the 'date'  column? I am new to python and still learning a lot. I have created other columns using the stock price data, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate the 'date' column.

For example, 10/26/2020, I would like to create columns with the following data:   
day_of_week, Monday = 1   
year = 2020   
month = 10   
day = 26   
week = 44   
trade_day = 207

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##Get stock price data
ticker = 'NVDA'

#Data time period
now = dt.datetime.now()
startyear = 2017
startmonth=1
startday=1
start = dt.datetime(startyear, startmonth, startday)

#get data from YFinance
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, now)

#create a column
df['% Change'] = (df['Adj Close'] / df['Adj Close'].shift(1))-1

df['Range'] = df['High'] - df['Low']

df
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the index of your dataframe, which is of type pd.DatetimeIndex.
To split the date into new columns:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df['year'], new_df['month'], new_df['day'] = df.index.year, df.index.month, df.index.day
```

To carry up arithmetic operations from the first trade date:

```
start_date = df.index.min()
new_df['trade_day'] = df.index.day - start_date.day
new_df['trade_week'] = df.index.week - start_date.week
new_df['trade_year'] = df.index.year - start_date.year
new_df['day_of_week'] =  df.index.weekday
new_df['days_in_month'] =  df.index.days_in_month
new_df['day_name'] =  df.index.day_name()
new_df['month_name'] =  df.index.month_name()
```

Choose another start date

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks Samer!I got the following error message: "weekofyear and week have been deprecated, please use DatetimeIndex.isocalendar().week instead, which returns a Series.  To exactly reproduce the behavior of week and weekofyear and return an Index, you may call pd.Int64Index(idx.isocalendar().week)"

Comment: I did get the 'Trade Week' working by changing the following: new_df['Trade_week'] = df.index.isocalendar().week. Also, the 'trade_day' is not correct if it's run from any other day in the year. I would like the 'trade_day' to start calculating on the first actual trading day of the year.

Comment: Change the start date:    start_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01')

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out most of the problem. I cannot figure out how to calculate the 'trade date'.

```
#Convert the 'Date' Index to 'Date' Column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

#Create columns manipulating 'Date'
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
df['Week of Year'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['Day of Week'] = df['Date'].dt.dayofweek
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbee to python but it appears to me that for some reason datetime sometimes does not read stored date as a string. I am on Windows with python 3 11 4 if I enter:
my_time=time.fromisoformat("15:33:08-07:00")
I get an error that this is not a time object

If I enter it as a string like this:
my_time=time.fromisoformat(str("15:33:08-07:00"))
time accepts it and it runs

Without the timezone offset time accepts it fine but when I add the offset it will not run without assigning it string properties

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34617599)